# How to style specific dates in material UI Date picker

Tags: datepicker, material-ui

I am using material UI Date picker. I would like to style specific dates in a calendar year like public holidays. How to style the dates in a calendar year? 
Lets assume, I have dates list and styling details.

Comment: This is currently not supported by the library, unless you're willing to modify the source code for the library

Answer (score 1):

@material-ui/pickers has relesed an update where the DatePicker takes a "renderDay" prop that is used to render each day in the calendar view.

So in your situation, for example:

```
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

...

<KeyboardDatePicker
    renderDay={(day, selectedDate, dayInCurrentMonth, dayComponent) => {
        if (isHoliday) {
           return 'Special component';
        } else {
           return dayComponent;
        }
    }}
    ...rest of props
/>
```

source: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker